# Running MongoDB Script with MongoDB Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I want to be able to run a MongoDB script using the MongoDB Java driver.

The script is comprised of a series of MongoDB commands with if-else branches. An example of such command would be the following:

```
db.myDB.find().forEach(function(record) { if(record.myProperty == "someValue") {print(1)} else {print(2)} });
```

I know of the option to use the `runCommand` Mongo Java API as follows:

```
Document doc = Document.parse("{find: \"collectionName\", filter: {somePropertyName: \"someValue\"}}");
Document result = mongoDatabase.runCommand(cmdDoc);
```

But this is limited to just one specific command and I want to be able to run a series of several commands with conditions and do additional processing.

I cannot separate the commands and do the processing on the Java side as my program receive the script as a whole from an external program and must return the result of the script back to that other program and I don't have any knowledge of the commands in the script beforehand.

I'm using MongoDB 4.x and up so the option to use `eval()` no longer exist there.

Comment: can you add the format of these script that you receive from the external program which has multiple commands

Comment: @Sathish there is an example of such a script in my original post.